# Menu slide toggle. Function not executed on screen width

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, screen, slidetoggle, slideup

I'm trying to make a menu for a responsive site. The click function already works but I want the menu to slide up when the screen size is smaller than 850 pixels but I can't seem to get the function to execute.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $( "#mobile" ).click(function() {
      $( "#fripple" ).slideToggle();
      $( "#site-navigation" ).slideToggle();
      $( "#secondary" ).slideToggle(); 

        if (screen.width >= 850) {
      $( "#fripple" ).show();
      $( "#site-navigation" ).show();
      $( "#secondary" ).show();
    }

    else if (screen.width < 850){

      $( "#fripple" ).slideUp();
      $( "#site-navigation" ).slideUp();
      $( "#secondary" ).slideUp();
    }


    });
});
```

Comment: What are you running this on to simulate `screen.width < 850`?

Comment: Chrome, changing the screen size.

Comment: Also checking with browserstack

Comment: Why would you expected the "screen" size to change if you have only one device? Surely you want to check the window or viewport size instead? View the difference here: http://jsfiddle.net/VsBdF/ Just resize your browser to see the values. Screen means literally your screen size, not the browser size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `.show()` is not needed anymore since you already `slideToggle()` the display has been changed to `block`. With `window.screen.width` your trying to get the device native screen resolution so use `$(window).width()` instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mobile').click(function(){
        $( "#fripple" ).slideToggle();
        $( "#site-navigation" ).slideToggle();
        $( "#secondary" ).slideToggle(); 


        if($(window).width() < 850){
            $( "#fripple" ).slideUp();
            $( "#site-navigation" ).slideUp();
            $( "#secondary" ).slideUp();
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, the menu keeps on going up and down on click with this code.

Comment: I thought that was what you are trying to do? Because on your original code the `if/else` is inside the `click()` event, try resize viewport greater than 850 before clicking. However, if you want them to slideUp only when screen resizes then you should handle it on `resize()` event, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/A9BGv/)

Comment: Thanks! Works fabulous!